# Footer not displaying properly in html

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am using two column layout.One for Main content and one for sidebar

In html I am using the following code

```
<div id="content">
     <div id="main-content">
       -----------
       -----------
     </div>

     <div id="sidebar">
      -----------
      ----------
      </div>

 </div>

 <div id="footer">
   ----------
   ----------
 </div>
```

CSS file Consist of the following code

```
  #content
{
padding-top:100px;
padding-bottom:50px;
width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;

}

  #main-content
{

width:720px;
padding-top:250px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    padding-right:20px;
position : absolute;
}

 #sidebar

{
float:right;
width:270px;
    padding-top:250px;
    padding-bottom:30px;

}

 #footer
{
background: url(../images/footer.jpg) repeat-x;
    width:100%;
clear:both;
    margin:auto;

}
```

The footer code is displaying in the middle of the page , probably at the end of the sidebar
you can see [here](http://jhakas.in/Forex/calender.html). Footer is in Black color.

Comment: you are writing the `footer div` through `javascript`..but y..there's no need of javascript in that cuz ur writing only `static content` through it!bring it back into html!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding-right: 20px` and `position: absolute` properties from `div.#main-content`

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position: absolute` in `#main-content` CSS. You don't need it. If you absolute position an element, then this is out of the document flow.

In this case, if you set `position: absoulte` in `#main-content`, its height is ignored to render the footer.